# Error in JColorChooser

Tags: java

I have written a simple codeby using JColorChooser to allow the user to choose Colours from the panel. But i am getting one error all-through. The GUI code has one button which performs an action of opening up of Color Panel when the user clicks it. Please help me correct the error!

```
import java.awt.event.*;      
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
class Colour1 implements ActionListener  
{  
JFrame f;  
JPanel p;  JButton b;  
    Colour1()  
    {
    f=new JFrame();  
p=new JPanel();  
    b=new JButton("choose");  
    }  
    void configure()  
    {  
    f.add(p);  
    f.setSize(200,200);  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    p.add(b);    
    b.addActionListener(this);    
    f.setVisible(true);    
    }  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)  
    {Color initialcolor=Color.RED;    
Color color=JColorChooser.showDialog(this,"Select a color",initialcolor); //ERROR found at this statement.
p.setBackground(color);    

    }  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
    Colour1 c=new Colour1();  
    c.configure();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing `this` as Component argument, which in your case `this` represents the `ActionListener`, So try this:

```
 Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(f, "Select a color",
            initialcolor);
```

Comment: It would probably be even better to pass the JFrame f, instead of null.

Comment: Why are we passing the JFrame object? Moreover after changing the code by passing the Component "f" compiles but gives an error during execution. The error is:  could not find or load main class Colour.

Comment: where passing a Component represents the parent of the color dialog, and about your current error, it's totally different issue.